# Jekyll Serve is not serving in localhost

Tags: terminal, jekyll

I've been using jekyll for a month or so and had no problems until today. I went to run jekyll in the terminal and was prompted with this:

```
Configuration file: /Users/jamiefitzhenry/desktop/casa/_config.yml
jekyll 2.5.3 | Error:  Address already in use - bind(2)
```

I seemed to fix this by finding the PID and killing it, however when I run jekyll again I get this:

```
 Configuration file: /Users/jamiefitzhenry/desktop/casa/_config.yml
 Server address: http://127.0.0.1:3000/
 Server running... press ctrl-c to stop.
```

When I put http://127.0.0.1:3000/ into my browser I only get the html of the page however nothing else is updating. When I go into my text editor (Espresso) and save changes nothing happens. This is my config.yml

```
# Build settings

markdown: kramdown
permalink: pretty

port: 3000

sass:
 sass_dir: assets/css
 style: :nested
```

This usually happens whenever I start to run jekyll, however as soon as I save the index.html the whole site updates in the browser, which is not the case this time.

I'm still very new to running commands in the terminal, however any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I am getting the exact same issue, did you find a solution?

Comment: The error `Address already in use - bind(2)` means that you have another process running on the same port. Do you have other informations about your problem?